# Does an illustration of Tochee from the Commonwealth Saga exist?

Tags: commonwealth-saga

One specific creature from the [Commonwealth Saga](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commonwealth_Saga) has caught my interest -- [Tochee](http://peterfhamilton.wikia.com/wiki/Hancher). My imagination is really bad, and I can not hold all the descriptive details in mind at once. I have tried to find some illustration, but unsuccessfully. All I found was this non-Tochee:

http://www.flickr.com/photos/rickpickett/7464577876/
<sup><sub>*(Dead link)*</sub></sup>

Is there an image of this creature?

Comment: Aw, you shouldn't have said "by making a drawing". Now it's off-topic.

Comment: @Mr Lister: Please elaborate on your bold statement. I can not find anything in the faq disallowing drawings, or friendly request to fellow talented sci-fi fans.

Comment: A fan-made drawing would only be conjecture, i.e. an opinion on how it might look. If you get multiple answers with different drawings, there is no saying which one is correct. There can't be a correct answer! Now situations like that are frowned upon.

Comment: @Mr Lister: You are correct. (As I see it; the questions on this SE can be divided into two. The ones that can be answered by citing books/movies/other sources. -and the ones that can never be more than a conjecture. e.g. regarding the working method of a lightsaber.

Comment: The working method of a lightsaber is conjecture so far as that no working lightsaber exists. But there ARE canon references discussing how lightsabers work in the Star Wars Universe.

Comment: I felt that my answer to this one was about as comprehensive as you're going to find without getting a real artist to do a mockup. Is there anything else you'd like me to add before considering an acceptance?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a very extensive description of the Tochee on the [Hamilton-verse](http://peterfhamilton.wikia.com/wiki/Hancher) wiki;

> The body is about three and a half yards long, coming up to a human’s
>   chest and shaped similar to a squashed egg. The hide is a dark caramel
>   bristly fur and looks like it is two sizes too big – the whole body
>   looks like it is covered in wrinkles and creases. Black fronds grow
>   out of these creases like seaweed but look leathery and dead in the
>   icy conditions of the Ice Citadel world. These fronds later recover
>   into their multicoloured feather state after leaving the ice planet.
>   Its mouth is a small lip-sphincter that forms a snout on the conical
>   end of the body with extremely sharp teeth arranged in a circular
>   array. The organs it uses to both see and communicate with are located
>   a yard or so back from the mouth. It is a curved pyramid made up from
>   three oval sections of translucent black flesh, with the one in front
>   twice as long as the other two so it could follow the body profile. It
>   communicates by creating images in the ultra-violet spectrum on the
>   forward eye. Two fat ridges of rubbery flesh ran along its underbelly
>   and rippled like snakes to push the body along. A second pair of more
>   bulbous ridges extended from its back, shorter than those on the
>   underbelly and extending only a little further than the eye. These can
>   change into various shapes and can help to lift objects too heavy for
>   human arms.

Following the description you end up with something like this...

[image: A Tochee]

And yes, I do realise the awesomeness of my artistry. It's a gift and I try not to abuse it.

Comment: There's also this effort. Not as good as mine, but passable I guess; https://i.pinimg.com/originals/65/fe/b8/65feb801c0fe6a08d214543d8fa99469.jpg

Answer (score 3):

[Kernovy on DeviantArt](https://www.deviantart.com/kernovy/art/Pandora-s-star-Characters-Part-1-449611510) has created the following fan made image hich includes an illustration of Tochee. The user notes the following on the post:

> Here is the first part of some character designs I made based on the novel "Pandora's star" written by Peter.F.Hamilton.
>   It's an awesome space opera that I do hope will be turn in to a movie.
>
> I tried to represent the following key characters:
>
> - Ozzie Issacs Fernandez
> - Tochee
> - Orion
>
> It's still far from want I had in mind but I hope some of you will like it.

[image: Tochee]